# How do I configure nagios with audio notifications?

Tags: nagios3

I need help to configure Nagios to send an Audio notifications for every errors that nagios detects on the network.

I've found on internet to realize that I need to install Festival but I don't know how to configure Nagios.

Is there some one who can hel me?

Nagios Core is 3.3.1.

Comment: I've resulted that using aplay with a audio file and not Festival.

Comment: Did you check this: https://ideasnet.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/ides-server-xiv-implementing-a-sound-notification-for-the-alarms-on-nagios-with-ubuntu-10-04lts-server-edition/

Comment: There is an android app called Notifry: http://code.google.com/p/notifry

Answer (score 3):

<sup>**This was done with the authorized written permission of nagios.com**</sup>

> There's been a lot of questions as to exactly how notifications work.
>   This will attempt to explain exactly when and how host and service
>   notifications are sent out, as well as who receives them.
>
> **When Do Notifications Occur?**
>
> The decision to send out notifications is made in the service check
>   and host check logic. The calculations for whether a notification is
>   to be sent are only triggered when processing a host or service check
>   corresponding to that notification; they are not triggered simply
>   because the  has passed since a previous
>   notification was sent. Host and service notifications occur in the
>   following instances.
>
> - When a hard state change occurs.
> - When a host or service remains in a hard non-OK state and the time specified by the  option in the host or service definition has passed since the last notification was sent
>     out (for that specified host or service).
>
> **Who Gets Notified?**
>
> Each host and service definition has a  option that
>   specifies what contact groups receive notifications for that
>   particular host or service. Contact groups can contain one or more
>   individual contacts.
>
> When Nagios sends out a host or service notification, it will notify
>   each contact that is a member of any contact groups specified in the
>    option of the service definition. Nagios realizes that
>   a contact may be a member of more than one contact group, so it
>   removes duplicate contact notifications before it does anything.
>
> **What Filters Must Be Passed In Order For Notifications To Be Sent?**
>
> Just because there is a need to send out a host or service
>   notification doesn't mean that any contacts are going to get notified.
>   There are several filters that potential notifications must pass
>   before they are deemed worthy enough to be sent out. Even then,
>   specific contacts may not be notified if their notification filters do
>   not allow for the notification to be sent to them. Let's go into the
>   filters that have to be passed in more detail.
>
> **Program-Wide Filter**
>
> The first filter that notifications must pass is a test of whether or
>   not notifications are enabled on a program-wide basis. This is
>   initially determined by the enable_notifications directive in the main
>   config file, but may be changed during runtime from the web interface.
>   If notifications are disabled on a program-wide basis, no host or
>   service notifications can be sent out - period. If they are enabled on
>   a program-wide basis, there are still other tests that must be passed.
>
> **Notification Methods**
>
> You can have Nagios notify you of problems and recoveries pretty much
>   anyway you want: pager, cellphone, email, instant message, audio
>   alert, electric shocker, etc. How notifications are sent depend on the
>   notification commands that are defined in your object definition
>   files. <sup>1</sup>

[Read More](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/notifications.html)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Nagios Notification](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/notifications.html)</sup>

<sup>**This was done with the authorized written permission of nagios.com**</sup>

> After installing alsa by using the command
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install alsa alsa-base alsa-utils
> ```
>
> after that we go to configure Nagios Core to use aplay as command-line
>   audio file player for the ALSA sound card driver.

```
> $: cd /usr/local/nagios/etc $: sudo nano commands.cfg
```

> adding the following lines

```
define command{  command_name    play_siren  command_line    /bin/bash
> /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/play_siren.sh  }
```

> create a script to run the sound alarm

```
> $: cd objects $: sudo nano play_siren.sh
```

> with those lines

```
> #!/bin/bash  /usr/bin/aplay -q /usr/share/nagios/etc/objects/alarm.wav
```

> give to it the permissions and create a log

```
> $: sudo chown nagios.nagios play_siren.sh $: sudo chmod a+x
```

> play_siren.sh
>
> modify the file contact.cfg to say to nagios of using the sound alarm

```
> $: sudo nano templates.cfg:
```

> modify the
>
> define contact{
>           name                            generic-contact
>           service_notification_period     24x7
>           host_notification_period        24x7
>           service_notification_options    w,u,c,r,f,s
>           host_notification_options       d,u,r,f,s
>           service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-email,play_siren
>           host_notification_commands      notify-host-by-email,play_siren
>           register                        0
>           }
>   <sup>2</sup>

<sup><sup>**2**</sup>Source:[ideasnet.wordpress.com](https://ideasnet.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/ides-server-xiv-implementing-a-sound-notification-for-the-alarms-on-nagios-with-ubuntu-10-04lts-server-edition/)</sup>

Extra References:

<sup>[custom checks and notifications nagios](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/custom-checks-and-notifications-nagios)</sup>